# COBOL - How to read and export text from .dat files

Tags: cobol, netcobol

i got a customer who wants to migrate from an old Fujitsu COBOL based system to our system, said that, he wants his old data to be kept in the new system, like products,manufacters, etc.I dont have the COBOL source file, i have: **.DAT files**, **.RDD files** and **.FDD files**. 

Apparently the .DAT files are in the **INDEXED** organization, a sample file output bellow:
**FDD output**:http://textuploader.com/kxdv 
**RDD output**:http://textuploader.com/kxdw

I can't simple read the .DAT file in notepad, i've tried the SiberDataViewer but unsuccesfull, also it gets paid to export the data.

If there's a way, can i write a program to export all these files to csv,dbf,postgres format?
 If you are still reading, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could convert it using the Siber DataViewer, but, its full version is paid.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Fujitsu COBOL but as I see it there are a few ways you might be able to get at the data:

0) Have your customer (or someone with a compatible Fujitsu COBOL compiler) write a COBOL program to read the INDEXED file and output a SEQUENTIAL file.

1) Find a Fujitsu COBOL utility to do the same.

2) Find a product that can read the INDEXED file and export it into something you can use.  I'm thinking of products like Cyberquery or Crystal Reports, etc.  Or, after I saw that the FDD/RDD files were produced by Siber Systems, a quick search helped me find their "Cobol DataViewer" product; use that to output it to a "more common and usable format" ;-)